# Filter by description JSON object expressJS/UnderscoreJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, underscore.js

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Take out the trash",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "description": "Get food tonight",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "description": "Hit the gym",
    "completed": true
  }
]
```

EXAMPLE ARRAY ABOVE.

I want to say get only the objects that satisfy a certain query.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var _ = require('underscore');

app.get('/todos/query/:des', function (req, res){
    var descriptionToFilter = req.params.des;
    console.log(descriptionToFilter);

    var filteredDesArr = _.where(todos,function(todo){
        todo.description.contains(descriptionToFilter.toLowerCase());
    });

    res.send(filteredDesArr);


});
```

How does this work? How can I input a function as a predicate inside of the underscore.where?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in plain Javascript with a right callback.

```js
function byCompleted(item) {
    return item.completed;
}

function byId(id) {
    return function (item) {
        return item.id === id;
    };
}


var data = [{ id: 1, description: "Take out the trash", completed: false }, { id: 2, description: "Get food tonight", completed: false }, { id: 3, description: "Hit the gym", completed: true }];

console.log(data.filter(byCompleted));
console.log(data.filter(byId(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscores `where` takes a key:value object as its argument, not a function. It's convenient if you know which properties you want.

Examples:

`var completed = _.where(todos,{completed:true});`

`var gymCompleted = _.where(todos,{completed:true,description:"Hit the gym"})`

`where` returns all elements that contain the specified properties, `findWhere` returns the first matching element.

If your filtering criteria is more complex and you need to specify a predicate, then you'll have to use `filter`, either thru underscore or native JS